# Protege: (SPARQL) Query Super class for individuals of Sub classes

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, protege

Having a Super class **Person** which has two sub-classes **Student** and **Staff**.  Student sub-class contains 3 individuals(name property): student1, student2 , student3.  Staff Sub-class  contains 2 individuals(name property): staff1 and staff2.

is it possible to query **Person** class and obtain all individuals as it is the super class?

How else can you go about this? especially when you have so many sub-classes?

Output similar to:

**Person**

**-----------**

student1

student2

student3

staff1

staff2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask for all resources that are members of either `:Person` or any of its sub-classes. If you use [property path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#pp-language), you would need only one triple pattern in your query:

```
SELECT ?person
    WHERE { ?person a/rdfs:subClassOf*  :Person}
```

This query asks for resources that are members of the class `:Person`, which is the case when the star is zero, or are members of any of its subclasses, which is the case when the star is one and more.

If needed, you can further restrict the subject to be `owl:NamedIndividual`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's been giving me a headache. Please can you explain  a/rdfs:subClassOf*.

Comment: I believe I did but if after reading about property paths in the SPARQL specs, it's still unclear, you can post a separate question on that as it has no specific relation to this one.